# SQL query not doing anything

Tags: sql, exec

I am trying to delete a row from my wp_pagesvisites table.

```
global $wpdb;
$time = time();


$timebd = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT Timestamp FROM wp_pagesvisites");


foreach ($timebd as $v)
{
    //echo ($time - $v)."  -  ";

    if ($v - $time > 600)
    {   

        $wpdb->query(   
                $wpdb->exec(
                    "DELETE FROM wp_pagesvisites WHERE Timestamp=$v"
                )
        );
    }
}
```

It does enter my if condition because if I do an echo on $time - $v, some are greater than 600, so I think it's my SQL query that is no good. Hopefully you can see my error.

Comment: Have you done a test select using that same where clause and made sure there is indeed a row that matches?

Comment: It would help if we got to see your table structure, as well as sample row of that table.  Are you sure the timestamp that you are sending is one that exists in the database?

Comment: Why would the timestamp in the database be greater than the current time?

Comment: Your echo is correct, your if is wrong (should be $time - $v).

Comment: @Paul you are right...problem solved! well at least, this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you say " `$time - $v`, some are greater than 600" but your if condition is vice versa (i.e. `$v - $time`)

Answer (score 1):

Warning - you appear to be open to SQL Injection, you should be using parameterized queries.  Also, you're going about this in the most inefficient way possible (by looping over every row).  What you should be doing is telling SQL to delete rows over a certain age; something along these lines (may need tweaks to work in your environment/language):

```
$time = time() - 600;

$wpdb->query(   
     $wpdb->exec(
          "DELETE FROM wp_pagesvisites WHERE Timestamp < $time"
     )
);
```

... And that should remove all the rows for you.

---

Besides the problem that @mavili mentions, you're also thinking about date/time/timestamps wrong.  You're comparing all values to themselves, when you want everything within a certain range.  It's almost best to think of timestamps like doubles - they can't be exactly compared to each other, only as parts of ranges (`>=`, `<`, etc).

Comment: Awesome answer. Thanks!! It's true I was doing it in a very stupid way lol.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

$bdd your database

$wpdb = $bdd->prepare("DELETE FROM wp_pagesvisites WHERE Timestamp <'$v' ");
$wpdb->execute();

or

$req = $bdd->exec("DELETE FROM wp_pagesvisites WHERE Timestamp < '$v' ");